# Check if nested dictionary key same as item in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

This might be a super easy question for most, but a struggling student would appreciate some help.
I have a dictionary with a list of nested dictionaries.
Some of the items are missing or in the wrong order.

I'm trying to export it so csv in a specific order (list)
I need to compare if items in the list key names and return the values. If the key doesn't exist to return 'N/A'

**Sample**

```
my_list=["_id", "count", "f_name", "l_name", "number", "country]

my_dict = [{
    "_id": 123,
    "count": 345,
    "account": [
        {
            "f_name": "Adam",
            "l_name": "Adamson",
            "number": 1,
            "country": "Argentina"
        },
        {,
            "l_name": "Charlson",
            "country": "Canada"

        },
        {
            "f_name": "David",
            "country": "Denmark",
            "number": 3,
            "l_name": "Davidson"
        },
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 678,
    "count": 981,
    "account": [
        {
            "f_name": "Edvin",
            "number": 4,
            "country": "Equador"
        },      
    ]
}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
_id   | count | f_name | l_name   | number | country
------------------------------------------------------
123   | 345   | Adam   | Adamson  |   1    | Argentina
------------------------------------------------------
123   | 345   | N/A    | Charlosn |  N/A   | Canada
------------------------------------------------------
123   | 345   | David  | Davidson |   3    | Denmark
------------------------------------------------------
678   | 981   | Edwin  | N/A      |   4    | Equador
------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but the keys in a python dictionary are not ordered.  If you want it to behave like a list you need to use an OrderedDict instead of dict. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.

Comment: What have you done so far?  You haven't shown any code for us to debug.

Comment: @shrewmouse, this was true before python3.6. Then [order-preserving feature was introduced as an implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict). From 3.7 this feature is guaranteed for regular dicts. And in any case it's not clear if it is relevant to OP question anyway.

Comment: @shrewmouse sorry, you're right - just a second. 
Re. OrderedDict, I tried it and it gets back with an error : "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: @buran the order is not important within the dict. It is only important that the values are placed in the correct fields and don't shift if the key doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a loop like this one.

```py
fmtstr = "{:<4} | {:<6} | {:<8} | {:<8} | {:^6} | {:<8}"
line = "--------------------------------------------------------"

print(fmtstr.format(*my_list))
print(line)

for entry in my_dict:
    id_ = entry.get('_id')
    count = entry.get('count')
    for nentry in entry.get('account', []):
        print(fmtstr.format(id_,
                            count,
                            nentry.get('f_name', 'N/A'),
                            nentry.get('l_name', 'N/A'),
                            nentry.get('number', 'N/A'),
                            nentry.get('country', 'N/A')))
        print(line)
```

Using your data, the output is:

```
_id  | count  | f_name   | l_name   | number | country 
--------------------------------------------------------
123  | 345    | Adam     | Adamson  |   1    | Argentina
--------------------------------------------------------
123  | 345    | N/A      | Charlson |  N/A   | Canada  
--------------------------------------------------------
123  | 345    | David    | Davidson |   3    | Denmark 
--------------------------------------------------------
678  | 981    | Edvin    | N/A      |   4    | Equador
--------------------------------------------------------
```

If you need the data in CSV format the solution is simpler:

```py
print(','.join(my_list))

for entry in my_dict:
    id_ = entry.get('_id')
    count = entry.get('count')
    for nentry in entry.get('account', []):
        print(("{},{},{},{},{},{}"
               .format(id_,
                       count,
                       nentry.get('f_name', 'N/A'),
                       nentry.get('l_name', 'N/A'),
                       nentry.get('number', 'N/A'),
                       nentry.get('country', 'N/A'))))
```

This time the output will be:

```
_id,count,f_name,l_name,number,country
123,345,Adam,Adamson,1,Argentina
123,345,N/A,Charlson,N/A,Canada
123,345,David,Davidson,3,Denmark
678,981,Edvin,N/A,4,Equador
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps as a starting point
The output is supposed to be inside a csv. My issue is that every time a value is missing, it shifts to the side and doesn't write 'N/A'

Comment: You mean the output should be in CSV format?

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to understand how I can access the key values and place them in correct order since on CSV it keeps shifting. And I have to hardcode the header / field names because it otherwise will take the wrong order if something is missing in the first object

Comment: I think you'll never find a solution that works for a generic dictionary. If you think that some extra keys can be present in a future version of the data, just add a scan to check for all the keys and initialize the array `my_list` during the scan.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the typos in your list and dictionary, you can convert the dictionary to a table (list of lists) and export it using the csv module:

```
table = [ [d.get(k,a.get(k,'N/A')) for k in my_list] 
          for d in my_dict for a in d['account'] ]
```

Output:

```
for row in table:print(row)

[123, 345, 'Adam', 'Adamson', 1, 'Argentina']
[123, 345, 'N/A', 'Charlson', 'N/A', 'Canada']
[123, 345, 'David', 'Davidson', 3, 'Denmark']
[678, 981, 'Edvin', 'N/A', 4, 'Equador']
```

Then save to a csv file:

```
import csv
with open('table.csv','w') as f:
    output = csv.writer(f)
    output.writerow(my_list)
    for row in table: 
        output.writerow(row)
```

Of pretty print the table:

```
for row in [my_list,*table]:
    print("|".join(f" {str(c):10}" for c in row))
    print("-"*70)

 _id       | count     | f_name    | l_name    | number    | country   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 123       | 345       | Adam      | Adamson   | 1         | Argentina 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 123       | 345       | N/A       | Charlson  | N/A       | Canada    
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 123       | 345       | David     | Davidson  | 3         | Denmark   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 678       | 981       | Edvin     | N/A       | 4         | Equador   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```